# Математическая индукция

Tags: математика

Привет.
   Есть у меня два массива (два множества), содержащие символы. С помощью пару циклов и условий происходит объединение в один новый массив (множество).
Так вот, как доказать корректность алгоритма объединения с помощью математической индукции?
   Сам принцип понятен м. индукции, но в интернете примеры конкретно для док-ва каких-то выражений.. А тут я не пойму как подлезть.

```
function Union(a, b) { // Объединение
var arr;
arr = new Array();
var i = 0;
var j = 0;
while (i < a.length) { // Объединение
    j = 0;
    while (j < b.length) {
        if (arr.indexOf(a[i]) == -1) {
        arr.push(a[i]);
        }
        if (arr.indexOf(b[j]) == -1) {
        arr.push(b[j]);
        }
    j++;
}
i++;
}
arr.sort();
arr = arr.join(' ')

return arr;
}
```

Comment: А в чем собственно проблема?    
Если речь идет об множестве, т.е. наборе уникальных объектов, и об объединении двух множеств, как о создании множества уникальных объектов, уникальных для каждого из первых двух множеств, то корректность очевидна из построения...

Comment: Проблема в том, что, если вспомнить м. индукцию: P(1), P(n), P(n+1) - и вроде как алгоритм доказан. Но в моем случае 1, n, n+1 что это, не понимаю

Comment: а ты опиши алгоритм свой, подумаем.

Comment: Выше написал код.
С помощью цикла идем по обоим массивам и запихиваем элементы в новый массив, предварительно с помощью фукнции indexOf проверяем, есть ли он там уже или нет.

Comment: У меня вот такое замечание: если исходные 2 массива являются множествами, что, на сколько я понимаю, в твоей задаче представляются как множества уникальных объектов (т.е. в любом массиве нет повторяющихся элементов), то к чему такая сложность алгоритма объединения? Почему нельзя сначала просто в "объединенный" массив сложить, например, первый из исходных массивов, а дальше сравнивать значиния, проходя по второму?

Comment: Так тоже можно, просто мой алгоритм пришел в голову первее :)

Comment: @Gikas, алгоритм стоит пересмотреть, может тогда и с доказательством будет проще? Очень уж странный алгоритм. В чем смысл вложенных циклов? Зачем во втором цикле по **j** много-много раз пытаться добавлять один и тот же **i-й** элемент a[i] (он все равно будет добавлен максимум 1 раз)? Первый - не значит лучший, @Stas0n правильный вариант вам предложил.

Comment: Причем тут вообще сложность/легкость алгоритма. Мне не понятно вот что: как вообще доказать, если мы имеем два множества, а не математическое выражение, цифры, как в теории по математической индукции. 
Сделаю я, допустим, алгоритм легче. А смысл? На входе все равно два массива будут.

Answer (score 1):

Стоит переписать алгоритм. Для алгоритма без вложенных циклов применять МИ будет гораздо легче. Воспользуюсь вариантом [@Stas0n](/users/9148/stas0n):

```
function Union(a, b) {
  var arr = new Array();
  var i;
  // Предполагается, что элементы массивов a и b уникальны
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) arr.push(a[i]);
  for (i = 0; i < b.length; i++) if (arr.indexOf(b[i]) == -1) arr.push(b[i]);
  arr.sort();
  return arr.join(' ');
}
```

Тогда МИ идет просто по циклу. По-хорошему, надо разбить процесс доказательства на две стадии:

1. Доказать, что после первого цикла arr содержит копию a
2. Доказать, что после второго цикла arr содержит объединение множеств

Первую стадию я пропущу, т.к. она уж слишком элементарна. На втором по индукции доказываем, что на i-м шаге arr содержит объединение a и первых i элементов b.

Comment: Я что-то не понял. Мы можем только на веру показать, что получилось объединенное множество, а как доказать?

Comment: Я же написал как :)
Что конкретно не понятно?

Comment: Доказать, что после первого цикла arr содержит копию a
Доказать, что после второго цикла arr содержит объединение множеств

Как вообще это возможно доказать? Если только показать как выполняется программа. А на листочке как?

Comment: Во-первых, перевести код с С++ на математический язык. Ввести, к примеру, переменную Arr_i, показывающую состояние arr на i-м шаге цикла. На первом шаге индукции Arr_0 = a. Предположить, что Arr_i = a | b.subArray(0, i). Доказать, что Arr_i+1 = a | b.subArray(0, i + 1). Я не помню, как точно это следует записывать, но идею я дал.  
Можете задать аналогичный вопрос на math.hashcode.ru, кстати. Возможно, там лучше распишут.

Comment: > Доказать, что после первого цикла arr содержит копию a
Кодом копирнули один массив в другой. Вопрос, почему второй содержит копию первого массива представляется уж совсем глупым..

Comment: В общем, спасибо Вам, попытаюсь дальше разобраться.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще слабо понимаю, зачем тут доказывать по индукции (очевидно из построения алгоритма), но попробуем:

1. n = 1 (в нашем объединении 1 элемент). Тогда добавляем в объединенное множество элемент, не равный данному либо из множества `а` либо из множества `b`. Алгоритм так устроен, что, если какой-либо элемент исходных множеств совпадает с каким-либо из тех, что в объединенном множестве, то не добавляем его в объединение.
2. Рассматриваем случай, когда в объединенном множестве k элементов. Все они уникальные и объединенный скоп элементов действительно попадает под определение множества. Рассматривает очередного кандидата (из любого из множеств, хотя, на самом деле, из множества `a`, т.к. еще на первом шаге все уникальные элементы множества `b` будут добавлены в объединенное множество) на добавление в него. Алгоритм не добавит этого кандидата, если такой уже есть в объединенном множестве. Раз так, то тот скоп элементов, в который добавляем элементы по-прежнему будет множеством.

Как-то так, поправьте если что..... Хотя, вообще, мне кажется бредово очевидное доказывать матиндукцией. 
Кроме того, реализованный алгоритм уж слишком затратен... Грех писать такой код.  
И еще одно - если рассматривать все это дело с точки зрения математики, т.е. все четко, то, нельзя смешивать понятия массива и множества при описании исходных массивов(или множеств) нельзя. Множество - априори является набором уникальных элементов. А массив, может содержать и дубли.

Comment: Сегодня между делом спросил препода, но толком не понял, что он сказал. Он сказал, вроде как нужно описать выражением то, что делается в коде.
Еще он сказал, что n = a1 (первый элемент массива A) например.
:)

Comment: До сих пор не могу понять, что у меня базис индукции например?

p.s. а ведь у меня еще пересечение, разность, симметрическая разность, которые тоже доказывать 8(((

Comment: > Сегодня между делом спросил препода, но толком не понял, что он сказал

Может сначала самому досканально понять что нужно в задаче и у препа спросить что и как, а уже когда конкретика будет, тогда и задавать свой вопрос?   
Не стоит вести себя как незнающий чего хочет заказчик